# How to resolve or mask the 'SameSite' cookie error for a Chrome Extension using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, warnings

I am developing a chrome extension which regularly polls user selected websites. I decided to utilize XMLHttp request in the following pseudocode manner

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get',url,true);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (this.readyState == 4){
    if(this.status == 200){
      foo(this);
    }
  }
}
xhr.send(null);
```

however I am consistently receiving a warning (listed as an error) from the chrome extension interface regarding the SameSite cookies flag.

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at "url" was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`

As I understand it, this is an error with the site in question. However, since it is showing up as an error on my end, I would like to stop receiving this "red herring" as it were.

I am aware that I can turn off cookie deprecation messages at chrome://flags/ , however I am uncertain if leaving it alone will cause the errors to show up for users when I publish the extension. Also I am generally not a fan of disabling flags globally anyway since I am planning to make a website soon and would like to be warned if I mess up the cookies and I would rather not have to turn that flag off and on over and over. However if that is the only way then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are doing it from content script. Instead you can put xhr request in background script.

Comment: All the xmlhttprequests are being done in background scripts. I tried doing it from content scripts before to... dramatic failure. I'm forgetting exactly what happens, but I seem to recall Chrome doesn't like it haha.